# What do I need to do to raise a subfloor?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, engineered-flooring

We're installing an engineered wood flooring in a room that already has a plywood subfloor. The engineered flooring will be 1/4" shy of the height of the hardwood in the other rooms, so I'd like to make up that difference underneath. My original thought was to use 1/4" XPS but that seems like it may not work.

If I go the 1/4" plywood route, what kind of connection do I need between the two subfloors? Can I just float the 1/4" on top? Or do I need to affix them together? If the latter, would some 1/2" brads be enough? Do I need to glue and screw?

Comment: I'd screw, not glue. Definitely not brads. Just enough screws to keep them in place, mind you, no need to go overboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using cork as an underlayment? I believe they make them in various thicknesses, including 1/4". It's very easy to work with (you can cut it using a utility knife) and it helps dampen sound.

Comment: that's an interesting option! I'll need to look into that.

Comment: I ended up using cork. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

You could simply install a transition piece between the two rooms.

But if you're determined to get them to match up, then 1/4" luann board will do nicely.  Glue *and* screw - 1/4 bead of glue distributed evenly over each board, screws on a 1 foot grid.

NOT going overboard is what leads to squeaky, shifting sub-floors that make for a shoddy looking finished product.

Comment: screwing down some luann is fine, a layer of red rosin paper between layers will also avoid squeaks. I would put down some adhesive personally, takes out any bounce as well as squeaks.

Comment: What about using a cork underlayment instead of luann? Since it's engineered, cork won't interfere with the attachment of the wood flooring. Plus it'd give a nice sound dampening effect.

Comment: I don't understand why it's being engineered vs. not engineered has any impact on the attachment of final flooring?

Comment: I think he means it's a floating floor (because it's an engineered floor) so don't have to worry about glue/nails.

Comment: Exactly, engineered wood floors are often floating floors and don't need to be nailed down.